# The animation trigger "transform" has failed to build due to the

Tags: angular

Any one please suggest me while i updated angular/Cli as "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.0", i am getting below error.

Failed: The animation trigger "transform" has failed to build due to the
         - The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS pr
         - The provided animation property "transform" is not a supported CSS pr

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. I added the following code to server.ts to resolve the issue.

```js
Object.defineProperty(document.body.style, 'transform', {
  value: () => {
    return {
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    };
  },
});
```

Please see a document, which have to be defined before that:

```js
// https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/830
const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
```

I have taken a solution from here:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7101